# Symbolic Links to a subfolder

Tags: windows, filesystems, symbolic-link

**Problem**

This is my directory structure

F:\dir\lev1\lev2\lev3

Consider there are files at every level of this directory structure.
I'd like to create a Symbolic Link in F:\dir to the directory F:\dir\lev1\lev2\lev3.

Command Used

```
F:\dataset2>mklink /d symlink--lev3 "lev1\lev2\lev3"
symbolic link created for symlink--lev3 <<===>> lev1\lev2\lev3
```

When I open symlink--lev3 , it takes me back to the parent level i.e. F:\dataset2.
I even tried using Full Path but the issue remains.

Any idea why I can't create a symbolic link to a subfolder ? 
Is my logic incorrect ?

Comment: Try removing the "s

Comment: Are you running as admin?

Comment: removing "s did not help. AFAIK "s are used when the paths have whitespaces , but it does not alter functionality. Why should running as admin matter ? Yes I am running as the admin though .Thanks

Comment: From http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html: By default, only Administrators can create symbolic links. The security setting Create symbolic links' can be granted at: `Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment`. The link is worth a read by the way - it might give a clue as to what is wrong (although I couldn't spot anything else obvious)

Comment: yes the fact I can create symbolic links means I'm the administrator,but Microsoft has information on creating symbolic links to parent folders(like a symbolic link at lev3 to lev1,say). It makes no mention of how I'd like it to be implemented.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363878(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DavidPostill . I created another directory & things worked as expected with this comment. I know something is wrong with that particular directory although I still don't know what. Thanks a lot :) :) :)

Comment: The following works for me: `mklink /d test c:\projects\test`. dir now shows `<SYMLINKD>     test [c:\projects\test]` and `dir test` works as expected.